# Dynamic link vs. static link efficiency

Tags: c++, dll, static-libraries

I have an argument with another developer, I'd like to settle here over Dynamic Link vs. Static Link.

In Theory:

Say you have a library with 100 functions, each has significant amounts of code inside it:

```
int A()
int B()
int C()
..
..and so on...
```

And your application only calls or depends on one of them.

You have two methods at your disposal.

1. Build the library as a dynamic linked library
2. Build the library as a statically linked library

My colleague claims that linking the static library to our application, the compiler/linker will **not add** the code of the 99 unused functions into our executable. I claim it will. I claim in this scenario the only advantage is having a single executable and not having to distribute the library with our application, but it will not have significant size differences if we used a dynamically linked library approach.

Who is correct?

Comment: This seems easily testable.

Comment: Statically link the library, and see how much of a difference there is in the file size? Seems extremely easy to test. It probably depends on compiler and compiler flags being set too.

Comment: oh it's a theoretical argument. i thought someone would be able to confirm my being right :)   if no one can -- we'll go ahead with an empirical test ;-)

Comment: Dynamic link is more about memory sharing between processes (several processes share library code in memory, reducing total footprint in memory), not about disk usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends :-)

If you put each function in its own source file, or use the [/Gy compile option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa71f43%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), each function will be packaged in a separate section of the static library.

The linker will then be able to pick them up as needed, and only include the functions that are actually called.

Comment: The functions are all one file. One binary for the statically linked library.  Sorry. I should have mentioned it.

Comment: That's what the option is for `/Gy (Enable Function-Level Linking)`. The compiler will split the up in separate sections for the linker.

Answer (score 3):

It can depend on a combination of how the code is organized, and what compiler flags you use.

Following the classic, simple model of things, the linker would link in whatever object files in the library were needed to satisfy the symbol references, so if your A(), B() and C() were each defined in different object files, only the object file that contained the symbol you actually used would be linked into the program (unless it, in turn, depended upon one or more of the others, in which case, the linker would find object files to satisfy those references as well, recursively, until it either satisfied them all, or found one it couldn't satisfy (at which time you'd get the standard "Unresolved external XXX" error message).

More recently, most compilers can "package" functions into separate "modules" without your having to put them into separate source files to create separate object files. Details vary, but can reduce (or eliminate) the necessity for having each source file as tiny as possible just to keep what ends up in the final executable to a minimum.

So, bottom line: at least for the most part, he's right and you're wrong.

Comment: The functions are all one file. One binary for the statically linked library. Sorry. I should have mentioned it.